# jQuery.load() Retrieving partial page content causes duplicate ID in DOM

Tags: jquery

I currently have a JS function that allows me to load partial content from another page into the current page using jQuery.load()

However I noticed when using this that I get a duplicate ID in the DOM (when inspecting with FireBug)

This function is used in conjuction with a Flash Building viewe so it does not contain any code to retrieve the URL from the anchor  tag.

```
function displayApartment(apartmentID) {
    $("#apartmentInfo").load(siteURL + apartmentID + ".aspx #apartmentInfo", function () {
        //re-do links loaded in
        $("a.gallery").colorbox({ opacity: "0.5" });
    });
}
```

The code above works just fine in retrieving the content, however it just bugs me that when inspecting with firebug I get something like this.

```
<div id="apartmentInfo">
    <div id="apartmentInfo">
        <!-- Remote HTML here..... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone please suggest anything on how to remove the duplicate div?

Thanks,
Warren

Comment: What does Fiddler tell you Warren?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just that ID that is causing you an annoyance, you could either change that id, or remove the duplicate when the document is loaded:

```
function displayApartment(apartmentID) {
    $("#apartmentInfo").load(siteURL + apartmentID + ".aspx #apartmentInfo", function () {
        $(this).attr('id', 'somethingElse'); //change the id
        // OR
        $(this).children().unwrap(); // remove the second apartmentId from the DOM completely.

        //re-do links loaded in
        $("a.gallery").colorbox({ opacity: "0.5" });
    });
}
```

If it's multiple ID's, the only solution I can think of is to prefix all the ID's within the remote page with something, or load the remote page in an IFRAME.

```
function displayApartment(apartmentID) {
    $("#apartmentInfo").load(siteURL + apartmentID + ".aspx #apartmentInfo", function () {
        $(this).find('*[id]').andSelf().attr('id', function (index, previous) {
            return 'a-random-prefix-' + previous;
        });

        //re-do links loaded in
        $("a.gallery").colorbox({ opacity: "0.5" });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, I used the unwrap stuff.

$(this).children().unwrap();

Answer (score 2):

a way around it maybe

```
function displayApartment(apartmentID) {
    var parent = $("#apartmentInfo").load(siteURL + apartmentID + ".aspx #apartmentInfo", function () {
        parent.children(':first').unwrap();
        //re-do links loaded in
        $("a.gallery").colorbox({ opacity: "0.5" });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Reigel for this, i just went with matt's version of unwrap by using $(this)

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use This:

```
#apartmentInfo > *
```

Full Code:

```
function displayApartment(apartmentID) {
    $("#apartmentInfo").load(siteURL + apartmentID + ".aspx #apartmentInfo > *", function () {
        //re-do links loaded in
        $("a.gallery").colorbox({ opacity: "0.5" });
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't get any text nodes with this approach. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I came here thanks to *the Google* looking for what I believe OP was really looking for; a way to have **all** of the **contents** of `$(selector).load('my.html #apartmentInfo')` without the surrounding div.

E.g.:

```
<div id='apartmentInfo' data-from="main page">
    Address: 123 Hell Street
    <p>Manager: Hugh Jass</p>
    ...
</div>
```

...rather than the default behavior of `$('#apartmentInfo').load('my.html #apartmentInfo')` which results in:

```
<div id='apartmentInfo' data-from="main page">
    <div id='apartmentInfo' data-from="my.html">
        Address: 123 Hell Street
        <p>Manager: Hugh Jass</p>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

The use of `.unwrap()` above comes close, but results in this:

```
<div id='apartmentInfo' data-from="my.html">
    Address: 123 Hell Street
    <p>Manager: Hugh Jass</p>
    ...
</div>
```

...which is a problem if you have any attributes set on the `data-from="main page"` div that are not also set on the `data-from="my.html"` div as they are lost.

The code below retains the `data-from="main page"` div while stripping the `data-from="my.html"` div post `.load`:

```
var $apartmentInfo = $('#apartmentInfo'),
    $tempApartmentInfo = $apartmentInfo.clone()
;

$tempApartmentInfo.contents().remove();

$tempApartmentInfo.load('my.html #apartmentInfo', function (response, status, xhr) {
    $tempApartmentInfo.children().each(function () {
        $apartmentInfo.append($(this).contents());
    });
});
```

This code avoids all issues with duplicate IDs as described by OP (but the *contents* of the remote `#apartmentInfo` may have duplicate IDs) as the `data-from="my.html"` div is never loaded into the DOM thanks to the use of the detached `$tempApartmentInfo`.

Or... here it is again as a jQuery plugin named `loadContents`:

```
//# .load the specified content while stripping the outer-most container
jQuery.fn.loadContents = function (url, data, complete) {
    var $target = $(this),
        $tempTarget = $target.clone()
    ;

    //# Clear out the $tempTarget so we are left with only the base element
    $tempTarget.contents().remove();

    //# Pass the call off to .load to do the heavy lifting
    $tempTarget.load(url, data, function (response, status, xhr) {
        //# Traverse the .children, .appending the .load'ed .contents of each child back into the $target as we go
        $tempTarget.children().each(function () {
            $target.append($(this).contents());
        });

        //# If the passed complete is a function, call it now
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(complete) == '[object Function]') { complete(response, status, xhr); }
    });
};
```

NOTE: This plugin **always** strips the outer-most element in the loaded content. Also note that unlike jQuery's native `.load` this plugin does not remove and current content within the `$target`, but rather `.append`s the `.load`ed content onto the `$target`.